# Stokes Theorem and Metric Connection

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I am looking at an expression like

$$
\int_{\partial M}\langle D\psi, D\psi\rangle dx dy
$$
where $\psi$ is some (well-behaved) function $\partial M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. $D=d+A$ is the connection one form. As this comes from a physical background, I assume $A$ is proportional to the magnetic vector potential.

Now I want to apply Stokes-Theorem to it:

$$
\int_{\partial M}\langle D\psi, D\psi\rangle dxdy=\int_M d \langle D\psi, D\psi\rangle dxdydz
$$
I already know, there is a manifold $M$.
First of all, this is probably:
$$
\int_M \langle dD\psi, D\psi\rangle+\langle D\psi, dD\psi\rangle dx dydz
$$
here then my confusion with dimensionality sets in. I am simply told $D$ is the connection one form, but if $\partial M$ is an e.g. 2d manifold,  should, after applying $d$ the connection one form somehow change to reflect that it is know on a 3d manifold?
Explicitly, if
$$
D\psi=\left(\begin{array}{l}
\partial_x+A_x\\
\partial_y+A_y
\end{array}\right) \psi
$$
do I then look at :
$$
\partial_z\left(\begin{array}{l}
\partial_x+A_x\\
\partial_y+A_y
\end{array}\right) \psi
$$
or
$$
\partial_z\left(\begin{array}{l}
\partial_x+A_x\\
\partial_y+A_y\\
\partial_z+A_z
\end{array}\right) \psi
$$
And what is the reasoning behind the specific choice?
I am currently self studying differential geometry and would be very happy about any help.

Comment: For starters, if $\psi$ is defined only on $\partial M$, then it is hopeless to continue. And isn't $A$ what's called the connection $1$-form?  Connection on what?